# sfinae on function template instantiation

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, sfinae

I would like to check whether a function template can be instantiated for a given type. As an example, for the template:

```
template<typename T> void f() { T{}; }
```

I would like to assert that `f<int>` is instantiatable, and `f<S>` is not, where `S` is some type that would cause the definition of `f` to fail compilation if instantiated, say:

```
struct S { ~S() = delete; };
```

Clearly, if I know what the function body contains, I could write separate checks for each of the statements. However, this approach will not work if the body itself is unknown.

It appears that I can't use the usual sfinae approach to do this, as the function body isn't checked for deduction failures. Here's the [attempt](https://godbolt.org/z/oMFc6f) to play with.

Indeed, [temp.deduct.8](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#8) seems to explicitly disallow this:

> Only invalid types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type, its template parameter types, and its explicit-specifier can result in a deduction failure.

and the reason for the "immediate context" constraint seems to be in the very next bullet point:

> Note: The intent is to avoid requiring implementations to deal with substitution failure involving arbitrary statements.

If I'm understanding this correctly, and doing this is not possible, can I get an explanation for *why* this constraint exists? I *think* arbitrary *expressions* can be checked for substitution failure by users, so why would this be too much for an implementation?

If I'm misunderstanding this, and it *is* possible, could I have a solution to this problem?

Comment: The reason this constraint exists is explained in the immediate quoted statement that precedes you asking this. And, no, there is no way to do this, like that. What ***should*** be done is to have the template function ***itself***, use SFINAE to fail overload resolution if its template parameter cannot be instantiated for a particular type, maybe something like `template<typename T, typename=std::void_t<decltype(T{})>> void f()...`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That would require me to change the function itself. And in fact, the question assumes that I don't even know the contents of the definition, otherwise I would just sfinae on the individual statements within the definition separately, without changing the function. And that leads to, why can't an implementation do that as well?

Comment: Again, that is explained by the very statement you quoted. It is what it is.That's what we have to work with.

Comment: Ok, but if it's that way, I'm just asking *why* it needs to be that way? Seems a reasonable question.

Comment: @cigien: The compiler works with function declarations: return values and arguments (and template arguments for templated functions). It does not consider the body of the function until it has already made all its decisions (at which point you'll get a compiler error  when the "best" choice cannot be instantiated)

Comment: Which specific part of the explanation "why it needs to be that way", which you, yourself, cited -- "avoid requiring implementations to deal with substitution failure involving arbitrary statements" -- is unclear to you?

Comment: Users can check the validity of all the individual statements in a function. So compilers *could* do the same thing. Couldn't there be a mechanism in the language that lets users ask compilers to do that?  Something like `std::check_function_body(...);`? Compilers do eventually check the body anyway, so why not allow a way to do it in a sfinae context?

Answer (score 1):

As said in your question,SFINAE only occurs in "immediate context" and what situation subsumed by "deduction fails" are listed in [[temp.deduct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#8.1).
The error happened in you code will be ill-formed,which is mentioned in the standard:

> The substitution into types and expressions can result in effects such as the instantiation of class template specializations and/or function template specializations, the generation of implicitly-defined functions, etc. Such effects are not in the “immediate context” and can result in the program being ill-formed.

So,your program would be ill-formed when require instantiation of function template f for type `S`.

#### Solution:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> void f() { T a{}; }

struct S { ~S() = delete; };
struct Test{};

template<typename T,typename U = void>
struct is_sutable_type_for_function:std::false_type{};

template<typename T>
struct is_sutable_type_for_function<T,std::void_t<decltype(T{}.~T())>>:std::true_type{};

int main()
{
   std::cout<< is_sutable_type_for_function<S>::value<<"\n";
   std::cout<< is_sutable_type_for_function<Test>::value<<"\n";
}
```

Now,the code will work for whether the type T could be used for function template `f`

Comment: This is a clever decoupling (which it sounds like OP wants). Now we can use `if constexpr` elsewhere before calling the function. I'd still prefer the constraint came directly with the function (as in my answer), though.

Comment: @AndyG yes,`if constexpr` is invented in c++17 that can convenient to use instead of `SFINAE` before c++17

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you must put your constraints on the function itself for detection to work:

#### [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9X2FjZ) (C++20)

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> void f() requires std::is_constructible_v<T> { T{}; }

template<class T, class = void>
struct can_call_f : std::false_type{};

template<class T>
struct can_call_f<T, std::void_t<decltype(f<T>())>>: std::true_type{};

template<class T>
constexpr bool can_call_f_v = can_call_f<T>::value;

struct S { ~S() = delete; };
int main()
{
  static_assert(can_call_f_v<int>);
  static_assert(!can_call_f_v<S>);
}
```

Recall that C++ works on *types* and the body of a function is not considered part of the function's type.

Comment: I understand that this is how it works currently. Is there any fundamental reason the body *can't* be checked for valid compilation? Or is it just difficult to implement that?

Comment: I can't say I'm expert enough in my knowledge of compiler implementation. My guess is that it would make template compilation a lot slower, and it's already a large bottleneck.

Comment: That's reasonable. Perhaps an explicit request for checking the function body would make sense. Then one would only be paying for what one wants.